# Бот для Discord на Python | Авто-поиск новой информации и отправка в канал

Tags: python, парсер, бот, discord

Пишу бота для своего сервера дискорд. В общем есть сайт https://pikabu.ru/community/steam на котором мониторят раздачи игр на разных площадках. Я написал бота для дискорда который по команде будет присылать последнюю новость с сайта(последнюю игру которую раздают), но дело в том что я хочу сделать чтобы бот реагировал сам на новые раздачи и присылал уже новые новости о раздачах в канал в дискорде а не по команде. Как можно это грамотно реализовать. Для бота использую модули: BeautifulSoup, Requests, discord.py. Не отрицаю что парсер можно было написать лучше, но я пока что новичок в пайтоне, так что как получилось - так получилось. Вот и сам код:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!')
client = discord.Client()

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")

headers = {'accept': '*/*', 
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 YaBrowser/19.9.0.1343 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}

base_url = 'https://pikabu.ru/community/steam'


@Bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def free(ctx):
    #await ctx.message.delete()
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
    title = soup.find('h2', attrs={'story__title'}).text
    href = soup.find('a', attrs={'story__title-link'})['href']
    content_text = soup.find('div', attrs = {'story-block story-block_type_text'}).text
    date = soup.find('time', attrs={'caption story__datetime hint'}).text
    await ctx.send(title)
    await ctx.send(content_text)
    await ctx.send(href)
    await ctx.send(date)



Bot.run(BOT_TOKEN_HERE)
```

Comment: Периодически запускайте парсинг, например, используя `scheduler` или `celery`.

Comment: Думаю вам нужно смотреть вот в эту сторону: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py